# Maude in eclipse start error

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to run maude in eclipse(windows 7)but when I start maude I get this error:

```
bash: /cygdrive/C/Program Files (x86)/MaudeFW/maude.ico: No such file or directory
bash: line 0: exec: /cygdrive/C/Program Files (x86)/MaudeFW/maude.ico: cannot execute: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you has selected the Maude icon in the Eclipse preferences instead of the real executable (i.e. maude.exe). However, I guess you will have a similar error, since the path to maude.exe must not have 'spaces'. So my advice is to copy the MaudeFW folder to C: (or the proper letter in your case).